# React: How to make item like m2, km2 (have the number 2 in the top right of letter 'm')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, chakra-ui

This's my code:

```
<Text color={"black.400"} fontWeight={"bold"} fontSize={"16px"}>
    {totalArea} m2
</Text>
```

I want to make text appear that the number 2 in the top right of letter 'm'. What's it name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<sup>` tag defines superscript text. Superscript text appears half a character above the normal line, and is sometimes rendered in a smaller font.

So, you can do

```
<Text color={"black.400"} fontWeight={"bold"} fontSize={"16px"}>
    {totalArea} m<sup>2</sup>
</Text>
```